# How to use SOCKS proxy with yum?

Tags: yum

The man page to yum.conf describes several proxy related variables:

> ```
>           proxy URL to the proxy server that yum should use.
>           proxy_username username to use for proxy
>           proxy_password password for this proxy
> ```

But how to specify a SOCKS proxy?

I assume that the above is just for normal HTTP proxies ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tsocks` application can socksify every other applications

```
tsocks app args
```

Comment: Awesome, it is already available in the default Fedora repositories - via Google I just found 'socksify' (dante socks client) which is not available - and does not work on Fedora 17 when compiled from source.

Comment: How to use it exactly ?

Comment: tsocks is out-of-date, the latest update is back to 2002. It can't socksify yum/curl nowadays. Use `dante` instead. Its command is `socksify app args`, similar with tsocks. (and as same as tsocks.conf for command tsocks, you also need socks.conf for command socksify). However, to socksify `yum`, I recommand @Klaus 's answer. Modify /etc/yum.conf is better.

Answer (score 28):

Add this line to `/etc/yum.conf` (got the idea from the post by DaPillow)

`proxy=socks5://ip:port`

In case host name resolution through proxy is necessary, thanks to Danny from comments this would do it:

`proxy=socks5h://ip:port`

It worked for me using yum 3.4.3 on Fedora 21.

Comment: It doesn't work on RHEL 2.6.32 (64Bit) with yum 3.2.29 :-|
[ProxyChains](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proxychains/?source=typ_redirect) is quite standard for such a purpose!

Comment: proxychains seems fair enough. I've used it and I'm happy about it ;)
But in your case, I think the yum version is the problem: 3.2.29 (mine is 3.4.3)

Comment: Yes agreed, its just the yum version and 3.2.29 is the default for 6.5 Final Release.

Comment: Works on RHEL7 / CentOS7 (yum 3.4.3).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: and use `proxy=socks5h://ip:port` for hostname resolution through socksproxy

Comment: I like this answer! `tsocks` and `dante` cannot be `yum install`ed directly on CentOS 7

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by enzitib,`tsocks` can be used to use a SOCKS proxy with `yum`.

To be more detailed, one can use it like this:

```
$ export TSOCKS_CONF_FILE=$HOME/.tsocks.conf
$ cat .tsocks.conf
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 1080
$ tsocks yum ...
```

By default tsocks uses SOCKS version 4 - but you can configure 5 via the 'server_type' directive. For user/password options there are the 'default_user'/'default_pass' directives and the TSOCKS_USERNAME/TSOCKS_PASSWORD environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using CentOS6.x with yum-3.2.29-81, curl/libcurl 7.19.7-53 and have this same issue.  I have yum servers behind a firewall and want to use yum over a SOCKS5 proxy setup using ssh.  Ideally, I want to do this without requiring tsocks, proxychains, or any other "socksification" utilities.

I setup the SOCKS5 connection using:

```
ssh -D 40000 dmz-server
```

I poked around in the yum python sources and saw they use pycurl which wraps libcurl (also please note that all proxy environment variables--http_proxy, HTTP_PROXY, all_proxy, ALL_PROXY, etc.--were initially undefined).  Furthermore, I verified that ~/.curlrc was empty so it didn't taint my test results.

I wanted to see if I could get curl to talk through the socks5 proxy:

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:40000 http://some-server/some-url
```

successfully returned the remote web page, so that was a good sign--showing libcurl *can* use SOCKS5 proxies. However, defining an environment variable

```
http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:40000
```

wasn't enough:

```
http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:40000 curl http://some-server/some-url
```

failed.

At this point, I switched to using a Python test program *test.py*:

```
import pycurl
import sys
sys.stderr.write("Testing %s\n" % pycurl.version)
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://some-server/some-url')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, sys.stdout.write)
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

Now, running

```
./test.py
```

will fail to fetch, but running

```
http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:40000 ./test.py
```

*will* successfully fetch http://some-server/some-url.  So it seems to me that this (admittedly ancient) yum/libcurl combination that ships with CentOS6 is not correctly setting the proxy type within libcurl.  I think what is happening is that the PROXYTYPE is defaulting to a standard HTTP proxy instead of identifying the socks5:// scheme within the URL specified in the *http_proxy* environment variable.

In any event, the following patch to /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py worked to allow me to access http:// yum repositories through a SOCKS5 proxy.  Within PyCurlFileObject#_set_opts(self, opts={}), add:

```
if self.scheme == 'http':
  proxy = os.getenv('http_proxy') or os.getenv('HTTP_PROXY') or os.getenv('all_proxy') or os.getenv('ALL_PROXY')
  if proxy and proxy.find("socks5://") != -1:
    self.curl_obj.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)
```

around line 1205, right before

```
# ssl options
if self.scheme == 'https':
```

With this change,

```
http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:40000 yum install <package_name>
```

successfully connects to all my http:// yum repositories on the other side of the firewall through the SOCKS5 ssh proxy.

Of course, one could export the *http_proxy* environment variable within one's shell to avoid specifying it before each invocation of *yum*.

Answer (score 1):

`Proxychaines` also is a good option for you!

first download it and set your socks info in `proxychains.conf` file and enter `proxyxhanes` before any command that you want use socks proxy!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to `/etc/yum.conf` and make sure to use the expected protocol (not http):

```
...    
proxy=socks5h://localhost:1080
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `Options Error: Error parsing "proxy = "socks5h://abc.mnl.xyz.com:9999/ # "": URL must be http, ftp or https not "socks5h"`

Comment: `socks5h` inside `/etc/yum.confg` works with later CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat builds, for future visitors