# Emulating RHEL for apt get

Tags: linux, rpm

I am constantly requiring the use of multiple packages for my work, but alas my work PC doesn't have an internet connection. 
Hence, I am always stuck on downloading the package on a separate PC which has Ubuntu. 
I was wondering if it was possible to emulate my OS as RHEL6 and download the required packages to an rpm file via apt-get or something since most common answers to my problems seem to be answered in an apt-get install format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Docker` to spin up a CentOS 6 container. Then use `yumdownloader` to download packages and their dependency RPMs.

Comment: I haven't used Docker before. From the looks of it, it seems like something worth looking into. Theoretically, I think it could solve my question, so I’ll mark the question answered

Answer (score 1):

If your work pc has a network connection to the ubuntu system, you may be able to solve by using an ssh forwarding.

ssh has the ability to act as a socks-proxy.

the first step would be

```
ssh -D localport ubuntu-server
```

since yum doesn't understand socks by itself you need tsocks to work around this step like described here [How to use SOCKS proxy with yum?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43654/how-to-use-socks-proxy-with-yum)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the ubuntu and work pc have no link between them.