# Yum update with ssh socks5 tunnel on EL6 failed

Tags: yum, ssh-tunneling

I have to perform update on hasnoinet server.

I created the ssh tunnel on hasnoinet box and ensured that it works:

```
ssh -D 1080 hasinternet
curl --socks5-hostname localhost:1080 google.com
```

I defined http proxy in 2 ways:

```
export http_proxy=http://localhost:1080/
export HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:1080/
export FTP_PROXY=http://localhost:1080/
```

or

```
export http_proxy=socks5h://localhost:1080
export HTTPS_PROXY=socks5h://localhost:1080
export ALL_PROXY=socks5h://localhost:1080
```

I unable to use `curl google.com` and as result `yum update` fails. I am using EL6 Redhat.

Comment: I don't understand why are you setting the proxy for HTTP over SSH.

Comment: The original poster is trying to update a server that has no direct internet connectivity, and is trying to supply the missing connectivity by proxying the connections with SSH dynamic SOCKS5 forwarding through another host that *has* the necessary connectivity.  [See this answer: EL6's libcurl may have a bug that breaks YUM-over-socks5.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383277/258991)